# Altium - How to Convey Pin-In-Paste Technology in Design

Tags: altium, through-hole, solder-paste

I am working on the first board design I've done with a connector that requires pin-in-paste (aka. "paste-in-hole") soldering. We are trying to expedite the manufacturing process so we are leaning away from wave soldering and hand soldering. How is pin-in-paste technology conveyed in an Altium PCB design? I can't imagine it is as simple as adding a polygon on the paste layer *over* the hole, as that does not convey how much is pushed *into* the hole. Does Altium have a feature for this already, or should it simply be called out in the mechanical fab drawing along with the board stackup and drill drawing?

Pin-in-paste/paste-in-hole technology:
[image]

Comment: Have you asked your fab company what they require? They are usually incredibly helpful at telling you how the require various features to be indicated.

Comment: Hmm, I have not because we have several fab companies we use. I suppose I could ask a few and get a sense for what is the standard. I was mainly just wondering if Altium has a feature for this

Comment: Looks pretty complex with double printing or other methods being used. You can do it with polygons on paste layer- prolly the PCBA vendor will fiddle with it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No, Altium doesn't have a feature for this. As for the amount: You need to specify it just as you said by adding a feature (e.g. a Polygon or a rectangle) onto the relevant paste layer. You might want to do this in your PCB symbol.

Altium doesn't make any assumptions on the thickness of your stencil (especially not if it's a stencil with multiple thicknesses) so it cannot decide the amount at all, that's up to you.